# Node Js Returing Full HTTP Page instead of JSON data

Tags: ios, json, node.js, afnetworking-2

I have a client ios app that connects, using afnetworking2, to a Node.Js backend that's supposed to respond with json data from a post route. Everything works great when testing on the localhost but when I deploy live on heroku the app sends the entire html of the index page instead of the json. I'm not sure how to fix this or even why the html is being sent to begin with. Any and all help is appreciated. I love the stackoverflow community! My code is listed below:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes/index'),
api = require('./routes/api'),
mobiTokenAuth = require('./routes/jwt'),
https = require('https'),
cons = require('consolidate'),
mustac = require('mustache'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
templatesDir = path.resolve(__dirname + '/templates'),
emailTemplates = require('email-templates'),
mysql = require('mysql2');
morgan = require('morgan');

var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', cons.mustache);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('combined'));

// Set content type GLOBALLY for any response.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.contentType('application/json');
 next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');    
  next();
});

app.disable('x-powered-by');    

app.get("/", function(req, res){
 res.render('index');  
});
app.get("/partials/:name", routes.partials);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 app.listen(port, function(req, res) {
 console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res){
 console.log(req);

 res.contentType('application/json');

 var data = {
  json: "test to see if data variable goes through as json data"
 } 
 res.json({data:data});
 next();
});
```

Currently returns:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
 <base href='/'>
 <body><div>Testing to see if html data is sent instead of json</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/api/signup', function(req, res){
 console.log(req);

 res.contentType('application/json');

 var data = {
  json: "test to see if data variable goes through as json data"
 } 
 res.json({data:data});
 next();
});
```

has two errors, next isn't defined, and next is called after you respond.

also you don't need to use `res.contentType('application/json');` doing a res.json() takes care of the headers.

Comment: still didn't work after I made the changes, all I get back is html data of the index.html page instead of the json

Comment: do you have any other suggestions as to why the server is sending html?